# In JDBC Code Only SELECT Query Works - UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE Do Not

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

In the following code the user enters Queries in a Text Area and submits the query.  I am running using NetBeans 8.0.2 and Glassfish 4.1.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.sql.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

public class AddressQuery extends JFrame
{
    // Database connection
    private static final String URL =  "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AddressBook";
    private static final String USERNAME = "java";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "java";  

    private boolean connectedToDatabase = false;

    private Connection  connection;
    private Statement   statement;
    private ResultSet   resultSet;

    // GUI components
    private JTextArea   queryArea;
    private JButton     submitButton;
    private JTextArea   displayArea;  

    public AddressQuery() 
    {
        super("Address Query Entry");
```

This code connects to the database successfully.

```
        try 
        {
        // Connect to database
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection( 
                URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD );

        // Create statement to query database
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlException ) 
        {
            // Disconnect from Database and terminate application
            System.out.println("Failure to Connect to Database - exit App");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Update database connection status
        connectedToDatabase =
```

GUI is set up correctly for user to entry query in text area

```
        // Set up text area for user to enter queries
        queryArea = new JTextArea( 3, 100 );
        queryArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
        queryArea.setLineWrap( true );

        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane( queryArea, 
        ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER );

        // Set up button for submitting queries
        submitButton = new JButton( "Submit Query" );

        // Set up placement of entry text area and submit button in GUI
        Box boxNorth = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        boxNorth.add( scrollpane );
        boxNorth.add( submitButton );
        add( boxNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Set up entry of display text area in GUI
        displayArea = new JTextArea();
        displayArea.setEditable( false );
        add( new JScrollPane( displayArea ), BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

Event Listener for user to process submitted query

```
        // Event listener for submit button
        submitButton.addActionListener (
            new ActionListener ()
            {
                public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
                {
                    // Perform a new query
                    try
                    {
                        setQuery( queryArea.getText() );
                    }
                    catch (SQLException sqlException )
                    {
                        displayArea.append("\nError performing query - clear entry");
                    queryArea.setText( "" );
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

The following is code to process entered query and print out the updated database for debugging purposes.

When I entered SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES (ADDRESSES is the database) I get:

Query = SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES

And a complete printout of the Addresses Table (meaning the query was successful):

ADDRESSID   FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    EMAIL               PHONENUMBER
1           Mike        Green       demo1@deitel.com    642-5088
2           Mary        Brown       demo2@deitel.com    555-1234

When I entered UPDATE ADDRESSES SET PHONENUMBER = '555-5555' WHERE LASTNAME = 'GREEN', I get:

Query = UPDATE ADDRESSES SET PHONENUMBER = '555-5555' WHERE LASTNAME = 'GREEN'
But an SQL exception occurs and I do not get to the code that prints out the contents of the database.  Case doesn't seem effect success of failure of queries.

```
    // Process query
    public void setQuery( String query ) 
            throws SQLException, IllegalStateException 
    {
        // If not connected to database - display message, throw exception
        if ( !connectedToDatabase )
        {
            displayArea.append("\nNot Connected to Database");
            throw new IllegalStateException( "Not Connected to Database");
        }
        // Execute query

        System.out.println("Query = " + query);   // debug statement
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery( query );

        //start debug code
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("Addresses Table:\n");
        for ( int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++ )
            System.out.printf( "%-8s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i));
        System.out.println();
        while (resultSet.next())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i<= numberOfColumns; i++)
                System.out.printf("%-8s\t",resultSet.getObject(i));
            System.out.println();
        }
        // end debug code

        // Indicate successful query
        displayArea.append("\nDatabase 
    }
```

Code to close connection and main function follow.

Comment: Try to use executeUpdate  instead of execute for UPDATE,INSERT & DELETE

Comment: Changed code to use executeUpdate if INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE in query but still doesn't come from executeUpdate command successfully                                                                                                                    if (query.toLowerCase().contains(insertStr.toLowerCase()) ||
                query.toLowerCase().contains(deleteStr.toLowerCase()) ||
                query.toLowerCase().contains(updateStr.toLowerCase()))
            {
                statement.executeUpdate( query );
                displayArea.append("\nDatabase Updated");
            }

Comment: changed call to result = statement.executeUpdate(query) and it worked.  Thanks!